# How to rollback an RPM to an older version?

Tags: redhat, rpm, rhel

What is the most efficient approach, when using RPM (RedHat Package Manager), to be able to "roll back" from a new version to an old version?

Ex: On Monday I install v1.7 of my RPM.
On Tuesday I upgrade to v1.8 of the same RPM.
On Wednesday I discover a problem with v1.8 and would like to go back to v1.7.

What's the best strategy to do that?

An obvious solution is to keep copies of both package versions on the machine somewhere and do this by uninstalling v1.8 and installing 1.7.

Might there be a better way of doing this? Might RPM have some better, built-in, way of managing the version archives?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yum, you can use this how-to http://www.indiangnu.org/2011/yum-rollback-and-repackage/